# Partitioning on GPARTED

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, gparted

I have tried over and over to partition my hard disk in a way so that every time I have to reinstall ubuntu, I wouldnt have to copy my data to an external device. I have followed all the possible steps on different websites but I havent yet made it to partition my hard disk in a 10GB space in which goes my ubuntu, and a **completely separated 235 gb in which go all my other data** without being lost the next time I format my pc! Could someone really help!!!?

Comment: You need to explain what exactly you mean when you say "the next time I format my pc".

Comment: in fact, the next time I want to reinstall my ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

> the next time I format my pc

This might have something to do with your problem.

You need to ensure that you only format the 10GB partition that contains Ubuntu, and leave the rest untouched.

If you are formatting using the Ubuntu installer, then you need to tell it not to use the "whole drive" but instead point it to that 10GB partition and tell it to use that only.

If you could provide more information about what you are doing when you format your computer, that might help.

Comment: Well it really doesnt ask me anything in particular about where to install my ubuntu, because it seems to me that although I try to divide my disk, I dont really make it. I would appreciate if you could tell me the procedure. I always do a (/) and then a (/home) but it seems the (/home) is kind of embeded in (/), since I always face a blank hard disk after every reinstalling!

Comment: Don't "format" or delete partitions, of which you want to keep the data and don't try to resize partitions that are filled to the brim to make them smaller. There is not much you can do wrong. Can you please post you partition layout (`fdisk -l`) and your last installation log (`/var/log/installer/syslog`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special with partitioning.  If you don't want to lose your existing data when you reinstall Ubuntu, then you just need to tell it to upgrade/replace the existing install, or do manual partitioning, tell it to use the existing partition, and do NOT check the format box.